# How to store sales data in custom table using magento observer (sales_order_place_after)?

Tags: php, magento

Kindly see below code

```
public function send_activation_code(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getData();
        Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')->getCollection();



        if (isset($cart['items_qty'])) {
            $getQty = (int) $cart['items_qty'];
        } else {
            $getQty = '0';
        }

        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $Order_id = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();
        $date = Date('y-m-d');
        $customer_id = $order->getCustomerId();
        $incrementId = $observer->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
        $phone = $observer->getOrder()->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
        $getEmail = $observer->getOrder()->getBillingAddress()->getEmail();
        $getFirstname = $observer->getOrder()->getBillingAddress()->getFirstname();
        $getLastname = $observer->getOrder()->getBillingAddress()->getLastname();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use **checkout_onepage_controller_success_action** event.

To get Order detail write below code in observer.

```
$order_id = $observer->getData('order_ids');
$orderData = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

you can get the order data on event `sales_order_place_after` with below code.

```
       $event = $observer->getEvent(); 
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        $order_id=$order->getEntityId();
```